# Java compiler error 'missing return statement' when using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, compiler-errors, return

I am implementing a method to traverse a trie (more specifically, I am trying to count the number of leaf nodes. The edges going into these leaf nodes all have a terminator symbol '#').

I am using Java and am getting an error when using this method:

```java
public int traverse(Node n){

        for(int i=0; i<n.getNumEdges(); i++){
            if(n.getEdgeChar(i) == '#'){
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                return traverse((n.getEdge(i)).getNode());
            }
        }
}
```

I do understand why I'm getting this error, but how do I get around it? Initially, I thought it best to pass `noLeaves` as a parameter, but after doing some research I found that the above code is considered better practice. I just don't know how to get around this compiler error. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: add a default return statement outside loop too

Comment: How is your loop supposed to go to the second step of the iteration if you return from the function at first step ?

Comment: @PavneetSingh This wouldn't make it better... compiling but still not working.

Comment: add a `return -1;` outside your `for() {...}` loop.

Comment: @DenysSéguret You're right.

Comment: @DenysSéguret So do I create a variable and pass it as a parameter?

Comment: @DenysSéguret actually i was just planning to solve the error while commenting :)

Comment: It will not count leaves, you have only one recursion termination, and it always return "1". I think you have forgotten to sum inside your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing a bit here, but I think the following is what you intended?

```
public int traverse(Node n){
    int numOfLeaves = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n.getNumEdges(); i++) {
        if(n.getEdgeChar(i) == '#') { // leaf
            numOfLeaves += 1;
        }
        else {
            numOfLeaves += traverse((n.getEdge(i)).getNode());
        }
    }
    return numOfLeaves;
}
```

This will sum the results of the recursive calls for all edges and return the sum. `#` is assumed to indicate a leaf and will count as 1 in the sum rather than doing a recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a case when `n.getNumEdges()` equals to `0` and the `for` statement won't execute. You should return a default value

```
return 0;
```

or throw an exception if such behaviour is considered illegal:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("There are no edges in the node!");
```

Comment: The way the trie is constructed (the data is stored in the edges not the nodes) ensures that if the node has no children, then the edge going into that node must be a terminator (#), so theoretically that shouldn't happen right?

Comment: Since the purpose is to sum, i suggest that the default value should be "0", but there are other programmation problems.

Comment: @StefaniaDamato, the compiler is not clever enough to understand your business/algorithm logic. It just considers all possible ways regardless of any conditions

Comment: If you can use the exception to catch a potential programming problem, by all means do that. When you don’t expect the code to reach that point, the `throws` statement is harmless. In the very unlikely case that you get there some day, you will want to be informed — the exception will make sure you will be,

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your function returning any value(in your case int), it must return any integer by the end of code. In your method, it is possible that function may not return anything the node is empty or null.

To rectify the error, do following changes to your code

```
public int traverse(Node n){
    int returnValue=-1;
    for(int i=0; i<n.getNumEdges(); i++){
        if(n.getEdgeChar(i) == '#'){
         returnValue=1;
         break;                
         /*return 1;*/
        }
        else{
            returnValue=traverse((n.getEdge(i)).getNode());
            break;
            /*return */
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```